# Check if all arguments are different from each other

Tags: haskell

I am a complete beginner at Haskell and got stuck at this.
I want to write a function that returns `True` if all 3 arguments are different from each other and give `False` if they are similar.

```
threeArguments :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
threeArguments a b c = if  a /= b && a /= c && b /= c 
    then return true 
    else return False
```

But I get error saying

> • Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘m0 a0’

[image]

Comment: The code in your screenshot does not match the code in your post.

Comment: please do not use pictures to display code.

Answer (score 7):

The `return` function is not needed (in fact, you must not use it) here. It has a different meaning in Haskell than in most other languages -- presumably you will get to that bit of your tutorial a bit later.

```
threeArguments a b c = if a /= b && a /= c && b /= c
    then True
    else False
```

(I assume the `true` instead of `True` in your question was just a transcription error.)

As an aside, the `if foo then True else False` is a really common beginner antipattern. Just use `foo` instead.

```
threeArguments a b c = a /= b && a /= c && b /= c
```

And, just for fun, there are other ways of implementing this. For example, you might like

```
threeArguments a b c = nub [a,b,c] == [a,b,c]
```

for its brevity and easy generalization to additional arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm getting parse error on input "then", am I missing something?

Comment: @buzzyso You would have to show us your exact code for us to be sure, but without seeing it my crystal ball says you have not indented the `then` more than the `threeArguments`.

Comment: I have added a picture above now. I did indent it more than threeArguments , I really don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @buzzyso There is no `if`...?

Comment: I removed it because it says 'if' is redundant.

Comment: @buzzyso Yes, that is suggesting the refactor I did, namely, changing `if foo then True else False` to `foo`. You can't *just* remove the `if` keyword -- you have to remove the `then True else False` part, too.

Answer (score 4):

`return` is a function in Haskell, part of `Monad` ([documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:return)). It’s not used any time you need to define a function’s value like it would be in some other languages. If you wanted your function to always produce `True`, for example, you would write it like this:

```hs
threeArguments :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
threeArguments a b c = True
```

`True` is a `Bool` value, and there’s no `return` involved. Likewise, the form of `if` is `if condition then trueValue else falseValue`, where `condition` is a `Bool` and the overall `if` expression has the same type as `trueValue` and `falseValue`, so you’re looking for:

```hs
threeArguments :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
threeArguments a b c = if a /= b && a /= c && b /= c 
    then True 
    else False
```

But `if condition then True else False` is redundant, because it has the same value as `condition`.

```hs
threeArguments :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
threeArguments a b c = a /= b && a /= c && b /= c
```